# Eloquent insert id with sequence next value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I would like to create a new record in a PostgreSQL database table with Laravel eloquent but the table id is not auto incremented and it's make my life more difficult.

Here is the sample structure:

```
CREATE TABLE billing (
   id int8,
   companyname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   ...
   PRIMARY KEY (id),
);
```

The **id** field isn't auto incremented and I can't change this. Furthermore I can't write triggers.

In Laravel I would like to do something like this:

```
$billing = new Billing;

$billing->id = DB::raw("nextval('sequence')");
$billing->companyname = $request->companyname;
// ...

$billing->save();
```

It's working but it seems messy.

How could I simplify the ***DB*** (id) part of my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$billing->id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId(); // + 1 ?
```

Answer (score 0):

with this

```
$nextval=DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT nextval('".(new Billing())->getTable()."_id_seq') as seq"))[0]->seq;

$billing = new Billing;

$billing->id = $nextval;
$billing->companyname = $request->companyname;
// ...

$billing->save();
```